# DrawerLayout с элементами из базы

Tags: android, sql, drawerlayout

У меня есть DrawerLayout из примеров IDE Android Studio. Я его немного модифицировал под свои нужды:

```
public class DrawMenu extends Fragment{

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    static int count;

    public DrawMenu() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_main, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        //ArrayList<String> mArStr = new ArrayList<String>(Main_f.db.Crsr(2).getColumnIndex("TEXT"));
//        SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
//                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Main_f.crsr ,new String[] {"TEXT"}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});

        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(Game_f.sca);

        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

В строке `mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(` я прикрепляю адаптер и использую в качестве набора значений `String[]`.

Но я хочу сделать что бы набор значений был динамическим (максимум 7), и брался из базы.
Попробовал SimpleCursorAdapter, согластно [примеру](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/278-urok-136-cursorloader.html) но `mData.execSQL(...)` почему-то не вытягивает и выдает `NPE`, заменил более простым вариантом

```
public static Cursor Crsr(){
//        mData.rawQuery("SELECT a.TEXT from NEXT_STEP as ns " +
//                " INNER JOIN QUESTIONS as q " +
//                " INNER JOIN ANSWERS as a " +
//                " on q.ID_Q=ns.ID_Q and ns.ID_A=a.ID_A " +
//                " where q.ID_Q=2;", null);
        mData.query(A_TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        return Crsr;
    }
```

Вообще не понимаю как работает это боковое меню...
Мне нужно что-бы варианты в меню брались из готовой базы.

Вот активити в котором присутствует боковое меню.

```
public class Game_f extends ActionBarActivity implements DrawMenu.NavigationDrawerCallbacks, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
    private DrawMenu mAnswersVariable;
    private CharSequence mAnswer;
    private TextView tvQuestion;

    public static Data db;
    public static Cursor crsr;
    public static SimpleCursorAdapter sca;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_frame);

        mAnswersVariable = (DrawMenu) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mAnswer = getTitle();

//        tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tV_H);
//        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
//            tvQuestion.setShadowLayer(30, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
//        }

        // Set up the drawer.
        mAnswersVariable.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        //Создал объект БД
        try {
            db = new Data(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.open();

        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                db.Crsr(),
                new String[] {"TEXT"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
                0);

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
    }

    public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                mAnswer = sca.getCursor().getString(0);
                break;
            case 2:
                //mAnswer = getString(R.string.title_section2);
                break;
            case 3:
                //mAnswer = getString(R.string.title_section3);
                break;
            case 4:
                //mAnswer = getString(R.string.title_section4);
                break;
            case 5:
                //mAnswer = getString(R.string.title_section5);
                break;
            case 6:
                //mAnswer = getString(R.string.title_section6);
                break;
            case 7:
                //mAnswer = getString(R.string.title_section7);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle(mAnswer);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            ((Game_f) activity).onSectionAttached(
                    getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        // закрываем подключение при выходе
        db.close();
    }


    // Методы Loadera
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor crs) {
        sca.swapCursor(crs);
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге все оказалось достаточно очевидно.

1) Я почему-то был уверен, что `DrawMenu` запускается после активити(`GAME_F`) в которой он используется, а так как базу я открывал в этом же активити, то соответственно вызов  `mDrawerListView.setAdapter(Game_f.sca)` из класса `DrawMenu` вызывал `NPE`.

Решил проблему проблему открытием базы перед созданием `DrawMenu`

2) Запрос был не совсем корректен и я его заменил на:

```
public static Cursor сrsr(int ID_Q){
       return  mData.rawQuery("SELECT a.ID_A as _id, a.TEXT FROM MATCHING as m " + //изменилось название NEXT_STEP - MATCHING
               " INNER JOIN QUESTIONS as q " +
               " INNER JOIN ANSWERS as a " +
               " ON q.ID_Q=m.ID_Q AND m.ID_A=a.ID_A " +
               " WHERE q.ID_Q="+ ID_Q + ";", null);
    }
```

причем важно не забыть `_id`.

3) В итоге получилось решить проблему проще, я просто содержимое запроса положил в массив `sAnswers`, который положил в шаблонное решение класса `DrawMenu`:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(

                    getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    sAnswers));
```

Весь метод в классе `DrawMenu`(больше в нем ничего не менял).

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.drawer_main, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });

        aCursor = Main_f.sca.getCursor();
        aCursor.moveToFirst();

        for(int i =1;i<aCursor.getCount()+1;i++){
            sAnswers[i]=aCursor.getString(aCursor.getColumnIndex(Data.A_TABLE_TEXT));
            if(!aCursor.moveToNext()){
                break;
            }
        }

        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(

                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                sAnswers));

        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

        return mDrawerListView;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Использовать `CursorAdapter` [пример SimpleCursorAdapter](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/111-urok-52-simplecursoradapter-primer-ispolzovanija), а также было бы не плохо `CursorLoader` + `ContentProvider`